# Each point is contained in precisely one integral curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As Corollary 2.2.1 in picture below, each point is contained in precisely one integral curve. But it is obvious there are different integral curve which contain the point. I understand 'precisely one' as 'only one', whether my understand is wrong ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: What is (2.2.1)? Maybe that equation narrows down what integral curves they are looking at.

Comment: Integral curves for a given vector field are disjoint in normal circumstances, so there really would be one and only one such curve. Without a picture or more information, I can't tell what your specific case is.

Comment: I'd rather say "one and only one" for safety.

Comment: Your English is correct. "Precisely one" = "no number other than one", which means not zero and not more than one -- just exactly one. In particular, it exists and is unique.

Comment: Please consider changing the title.

Comment: Note that the equation (2.2.1) is an *autonomous* differential equation, which simplifies the analysis.

Comment: <strike>@AloizioMacedo: Why change the title? Seems quite to the point in my view.</strike> I see now it was already edited.

Comment: @MPW The title was different. It was "Maybe it's just because of my poor english."

Comment: @MarkFantini: Ah, didn't notice the edit. My bad. I retract that comment (but will leave it there since your response wouldn't make sense in its absence).

Comment: @MPW Thanks ,I think I have understand it. For given smooth vector field ,there is a family of integral curve. They are disjoint and cover the $M$. So, for each point of $M$, the point belongs to only one integral curve. Yes or no ?

Comment: @lanse7pty: I believe that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of the confusion may come from the following. Given an integral curve $\gamma: \Bbb R \to M$ for the vector field $X$, then its translates $\gamma_t$, defined by $\gamma_t(s)=\gamma(t+s)$, are also integral curves. The difference is just where you define the starting point of your curve to be.

So this is a whole family of curves. But they have the exact same *image*, and only differ by (an incredibly simple) reparameterization. When the author says that a point lies in one and only one integral curve, he's identifying the translates above and considering them the same integral curve.